# Enviar variable de una función a una subfunción Python3

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo un problema con una variable que está en una función y dentro de está función hay otra función más, quiero enviar dicha variable de la función principal a la subfunción pero no me funciona, incluso he indicado la variable como global, esta es la función:

```
def ping_list():

    os.system('clear')

    def menu(entries):
        terminal_menu = TerminalMenu(entries)
        main_sel = terminal_menu.show()
        main_menu_exit = False

        while not main_menu_exit:

            if main_sel == 0:

                hola(fila_elegida)
                time.sleep(5)

    df = pd.read_csv(locali+locali2+archivo+".csv",sep=";")
    opciones = df.iloc[:, :-2].to_string(index=False, header=False,).splitlines()
    opcion = menu(opciones)
    global fila_elegida
    fila_elegida = df.iloc[opcion, :]
    print(f"Seleccionada fila {opcion}:\n{fila_elegida}")
```

Salida de la terminal:

```
NameError: name 'fila_elegida' is not defined
```

Comment: Independientemente de problemas de ámbito, no termino de entender la lógica, llamas a `menu` **antes de definir `fila_elegida`** en la función `ping_lists`, teniendo en cuenta ademas que `fila_elegida = df.iloc[opcion, :]` no se ejecuta hasta que `opcion = menu(opciones)` retorna...

Comment: La verdad es que yo tampoco entiendo muy bien la lógica, ya que tu me ayudaste con la función jeje, no sé muy bien en que línea se llama a la función menu

Comment: Como me dijiste que la variable fila_elegida contiene información sobre una línea de un archivo pandas, quería visualizar el contenido de esta variable pasandola a otra función para imprimirla

Comment: vale vale, es que el código que me pasaste supera mis conocimientos jejeje, de todas formas gracias por la ayuda otra vez. Probaré lo que me dijiste a ver si funciona :)

Comment: Lo que quiero es que cuando se seleccione una opción del menú, se coja los datos de la variable fila_elegida y pasarla a una función ubicada en otro archivo, y desde esa función se coja los datos independientes de la fila para pasarlo a netmiko y se cree una conexión con el dispositivo:

Comment: En plan, que se coja el usuario, contraseña, etc de la fila elegida desde el menú

Comment: Si solo es elegir una opción y llamar a la función con ella para establecer la conexión, aquí terminaría el menú, por lo que bastaría con llamar a `hola(fila_elegida)` después  de la linea     `fila_elegida = df.iloc[opcion, :]` en la función principal, si se requiere un ciclo por reintentos o lo que sea lo colocas ahí, la función de menu() termina cuando el usuario elige una opción. Si necesitas que se vuelva a elegir otra opción por fallo o por lo que sea, llamas a menu de nuevo sin más.

Comment: Okay funciona!!! Pero hago un print de la variable fila_elegida y aparece esto:  Seleccionada fila 1:
Unnamed: 0            1
ALIAS              luis
HOSTNAME      luiscisco
IP              2.2.2.2
SYST              cisco
USER               luis
PASSWORD       luissisi
Name: 1, dtype: object
Unnamed: 0            1
ALIAS              luis
HOSTNAME      luiscisco
IP              2.2.2.2
SYST              cisco
USER               luis
PASSWORD       luissisi
Name: 1, dtype: object

Comment: Aparecen los valores repetidos

Comment: Aparentemente tu función imprime también fila_elegida, quita la linea con `print` de mi respuesta anterior si no te sirve, en mi ejemplo de la pregunta anterior solo era para mostrar la selección, no hace nada más, si lo vas a procesar todo con otra función simplemente eliminalo.

Comment: Perfecto, ahora para meter cada valor en una variable de la salida de fila_elegida, tendré que exportar dicha salida de fila_elegida a un archivo csv y con pandas extraer los valores, para tener un resultado como: alias: sergio, sistema: cisco, etc...

Comment: Estoy teniendo problemas con la selección de la fila, no consigo "colocar" la fila como si fuera una tabla, la salida de fila_elegida es esta: ;0
Unnamed: 0;0
ALIAS;sergio1
HOSTNAME;router
IP;1.1.1.1
SYST;cisco
USER;sergio
PASSWORD;sergio

Comment: pero mete los encabezados junto al valor, no se como separarlos, está todo dentro de una fila